# How do I get the selected value of a dropdownlist populated from a database?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a `Quantity` dropdownlist populated with values from sql.

**View**

```
@Html.DropDownList("ShirtQuantityId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
```

**Controller**

```
ViewBag.ShirtQuantityId = new SelectList(db.ShirtQuantities, "Id", "Name");
```

In this case, how would I go about getting the selected value of the `Quantity` back to the controller?

Comment: Post the form to a controller method with a parameter (or model property) called: ShirtQuantityId

Comment: @NineBerry yes, it does :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you do

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.QuantityId , ViewBag.ShirtQuantityId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Comment: You need to cast the value from the Viewbag to the right type: `(SelectList)ViewBag.ShirtQuantityId`

Answer (score 0):

```
List<SelectListItem> items= new List<SelectListItem>();
db.ShirtQuantities.Each(a=>{
    items.Add(new SelectListItem{
        Text=a.Id,
        Value=a.Name
    });

}

ViewBag.ShirtQuantityId = items
```

and

```
@Html.DropDownList("ShirtQuantityId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
```